# How to stop automatic connector rerouting when moving bend point in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm trying to draw network diagram, but if I will try to bend connection line, it will be automatically rerouted. **I have automatic routing disabled in Developer/Behavior settings, even though there is rerouting.**

I drag bend point (first yellow arrow) to right. The magenta line is target design what I want:

[image: See attached image.]

But connection line is rerouted as you see in this image:

[image: See attached image.]

My opinion is that once the bendpoint is near the end of the line, redirection will take place.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different type of connector. Open the Connectors stencil: **More Shapes** -> **Extras** -> **Connectors**
Try the **Bottom to top 1** connector.

Comment: This example is OK, but If I need more sophisticated connections, I need the dynamic connector. But I resolve the issue by reducing page scale ratio from 1:25 to 1:1. I do not know if this is a good solution because I have to draw several racks. And these must fit into the A0 format. The VISIO CAFE website is advised to use the page scale.

Answer (score -1):

I have found that problem is in scaling. When is set 1:50, the problem occurs. When I reduce to 1: 5, I can bend connectors near start / end correctly.